# Rails ActiveRecord query where relationship does not exist based on third attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-record-query

I have an `Adventure` model, which is a join table between a `Destination` and a `User` (and has additional attributes such as `zipcode` and `time_limit`). I want to create a `query` that will return me all the `Destinations` where an `Adventure` between that `Destination` and the `User` currently trying to create an `Adventure` does not exist.

The way the app works when a `User` clicks to start a new `Adventure` it will create that `Adventure` with the `user_id` being that `User`'s `id` and then runs a method to provide a random `Destination`, ex:

`Adventure.create(user_id: current_user.id)` (it is actually doing `current_user.adventures.new` ) but same thing

I have tried a few things from writing raw `SQL queries` to using `.joins`. Here are a few examples:

`Destination.joins(:adventures).where.not('adventures.user_id != ?'), user.id)`

`Destination.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN adventure ON destination.id = adventure.destination_id').where('adventure.user_id != ?', user.id)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The below should return all destinations that user has not yet visited in any of his adventures:

```
destinations = Destination.where('id NOT IN (SELECT destination_id FROM adventures WHERE user_id = ?)', user.id)
```

To select a random one append one of:

```
.all.sample
# or
.pluck(:id).sample
```

Depending on whether you want a full record or just id.

Answer (score 2):

No need for joins, this should do:

```
Destination.where(['id not in ?', user.adventures.pluck(:destination_id)])
```

Comment: This gave the following error: ```(0.4ms)  SELECT "adventures"."destination_id" FROM "adventures"  WHERE "adventures"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 7]]
  Destination Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "destinations".* FROM "destinations"  WHERE (id not in 7,6,5)
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "7"
LINE 1: ...destinations".* FROM "destinations"  WHERE (id not in 7,6,5)```

Answer (score 1):

In your first attempt, I see the problem to be in the usage of equality operator with `where.not`.  In your first attempt:

```
Destination.joins(:adventures).where.not('adventures.user_id != ?'), user.id)
```

you're doing `where.not('adventures.user_id != ?'), user.id)`.  I understand this is just the opposite of what you want, isn't it?  Shouldn't you be calling it as `where.not('adventures.user_id = ?', user.id)`, i.e. with an equals `=`?

I think the following query would work for the requirement:

```
Destination.joins(:adventures).where.not(adventures: { user_id: user.id })
```

The only problem I see in your second method is the usage of `destinations` and `adventures` table in both `join` and `where` conditions.  The table names should be plural.  The query should have been:

```
Destination
.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN adventures on destinations.id = adventures.destination_id')
.where('adventures.user_id != ?', user.id)
```

Comment: I tried something similar to `Destination.joins(:adventures).where.not(adventures: { user_id: 1 })` the problem is that if a `Destination` doesn't have *any* `Adventure` record existing for it yet the query returns an empty relation.

Comment: I should apologize, `Destination.joins(:adventures)` does an `inner join`, so this would return empty relation.  Your second attempt as shown in my answer should work given that it is using `left outer join`.

Comment: it still is returning an empty relation, I have been reading through the SQL documentation and am unsure of exactly what kind of join I should be doing

Comment: Have you checked the data, are there destinations that a user is not in?  Perhaps a console test would help more.

Comment: A `User` does not belong to or have destinations. Those are entered server-side. The `Adventure` is a `join_table` between a `User` and a `Destination`.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord doesn't do join conditions but you can use your User `destinations` relation (eg a `has_many :destinations, through: adventures`) as a sub select which results in a `WHERE NOT IN (SELECT...)`

The query is pretty simple to express and doesn't require using sql string shenanigans, multiple queries or pulling back temporary sets of ids:

```
Destination.where.not(id: user.destinations)
```

If you want you can also chain the above realation with additional where terms, ordering and grouping clauses.

Comment: I'm not looking for `Adventures` I'm looking for `Destinations`.

Comment: A `User` does not have `Destinations`, only `Adventures`. An `Adventure` is a join between a `User` and a `Destination`. So when creating a new `Adventure` I have to check to see whether a `User` has already visited a certain `Destination` based on whether or not an `Adventure` with that existing `destination_id` and `user_id` exists.

Comment: Correct a user does not have destinations and that is why I described the relation with "has_many through adventures". This allows you to easily access destinations off the user model through the adventures relation and more importantly return a scope/relation that you can use in the where clause as my example shows.  The active record documentation explains the use of "through". You can even control eager loading using it so its worth understanding how to use it.

Comment: I understand the use of through. My `User` model has a `has_many :visited_destinations, ->{ where(adventures: {status: 'completed'}) }, through: :adventures, source: :destination` on it, but I was unsure of how to use that in constructing a query. When searching for `Destinations` I am only looking for ones that the `User` has actually completed the adventure through. I did `Destination.where.not(id: user.visited_destinations)` but that took 20.3ms vs the answer I selected only taking 0.6ms.

Comment: Sounds like you are getting additional terms you don't need included.  You can define as many relationships, one just plain without conditions, and others filtered as you have done. I typically use an unscoped relationship where the condition doesn't depend on something in the parent model model and just add a scope on the related model, in your case doing ``user.adventures.completed`` or ``user.adventures.started``  Also consider adding an index on status if that is a common query.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with a mix of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25627140/991138) and [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25674384/991138) and came out with:

```
destination = Destination.where
                         .not(id: Adventure.where(user: user)
                                           .pluck(:destination_id)
                         )
                         .sample
```

The `.not(id: Adventure.where(user: user).pluck(:destination_id))` part excludes destinations present in previous adventures of the user.

The `.sample` part will pick a random destination from the results.